# Changing column types with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need some help tidying my data.  I'm trying to convert some integers to factors (but not all integers to factors).  I think I can do with selecting the variables in question but how do I add them back to the original data set?  For example, keeping the values NOT selected from my raw_data_tbl and using the mutated types from the `raw_data_tbl_int`

[image]

[image]

```
    library(dplyr)

    raw_data_tbl %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    select(-c(contains("units"), PRO_ALLOW, RTL_ACTUAL, REAL_PRICE, 
           REAL_PRICE_HHU, REBATE, RETURN_UNITS, UNITS_PER_CASE, Profit, STR_COST, DCC, 
           CREDIT_AMT)) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor)
```

Comment: transformed_raw_data_tbl <- raw_data_tbl %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("units"), PRO_ALLOW, RTL_ACTUAL, REAL_PRICE, REAL_PRICE_HHU,
                 REBATE, RETURN_UNITS, Profit, STR_COST, DCC, CREDIT_AMT),
            funs(as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-contains("units"), -PRO_ALLOW, -RTL_ACTUAL, -REAL_PRICE, -REAL_PRICE_HHU,
                 -REBATE, -RETURN_UNITS, -Profit, -STR_COST, -DCC, -CREDIT_AMT),
            funs(as.factor))

Comment: This code got me where I wanted to be.  Preserving the integer type of the variables that I wanted to keep as integers and changing the rest to factors.

Answer (score 20):

As of dplyr 1.0.0 released on CRAN 2020-06-01, the scoped functions `mutate_at()`, `mutate_if()` and `mutate_all()` have been superseded thanks to the more generalizable `across()`. This means you can stay with just `mutate()`. [The introductory blog post from April](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/) explains why it took so long to discover.

Toy example:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  mutate(across(c(Sepal.Width, 
                  Sepal.Length),
                factor))
```

In your case, you'd do this:

```
library(dplyr)

raw_data_tbl %>% 
  mutate(across(c(is.numeric,
                  -contains("units"),
                  -c(PRO_ALLOW, RTL_ACTUAL, REAL_PRICE, REAL_PRICE_HHU,
                     REBATE, RETURN_UNITS, UNITS_PER_CASE, Profit,
                     STR_COST, DCC, CREDIT_AMT)),
                factor))
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `mutate_at` instead.  Here's an example using the `iris` dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

iris_factor <- iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Width, 
                 Sepal.Length), 
            funs(factor))
```

---

### Edit 08/2020

As of dplyr 0.8.0, `funs()` is deprecated. Use `list()` instead, as in

```
library(dplyr)

iris_factor <- iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Width, 
                 Sepal.Length), 
            list(factor))
```

And the proof:

```
> str(iris_factor)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: Factor w/ 35 levels "4.3","4.4","4.5",..: 9 7 5 4 8 12 4 8 2 7 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : Factor w/ 23 levels "2","2.2","2.3",..: 15 10 12 11 16 19 14 14 9 11 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: if using tidyverse then this will work:

`iris %>% mutate_at(c('Sepal.Width', 'Sepal.Length'), factor)` or `iris %>% mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length), factor)`

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, I'd do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame("LOC_ID" = c(1,2,3,4),
                "STRS" = c("a","b","c","d"),
                "UPC_CDE" = c(813,814,815,816))

df$LOC_ID = as.factor(df$LOC_ID)
df$UPC_CDE = as.factor(df$UPC_CDE)
```

Comment: You don't need `dplyr` to make changes like this

Comment: @DaveGruenewald It's only in there because OP had it in their code. You're of course right. FWIW, I think your solution is better and I was hoping OP would accept it.

Comment: always a fan of not relying on packages when you don't have to, so there's a time and a place for both of our solutions!